# TYPO3 8.7 TCA inputLink Fluid result

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I was using the page wizard, but after upgrade i had to switch to the

```
'renderType' => 'inputLink',
```

in my extensions TCA. 
This results the following output:

```
t3://page?uid=19
```

If i debug the variable in my template, this is shown:

```
<f:debug>{domainmodel.page}</f:debug>
    external => 'http://t3://page?uid=19' (23 chars)
```

Whats to correct way to show the Link in my extension template?

Comment: Had something in .page getter that manipulated the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the [`f:link.typolink` viewhelper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Link/Typolink.html) for this.

Comment: sadly, no. <f:link.typolink parameter="{page}">Linktext</f:link.typolink> Results in just 'Linktext' - without any a tag. 
By the way. f:debug says "http://t3://page?uid=19" - IMHO that http:// shouldn´t be there

Comment: i get page from domainmodel.page. Dump on domainmodel shows just t3://page... Dump on domainmodel.page shows http://t3://pge..

Comment: Just checked. It stepts into TypoLinkCodecService, calls decode($typoLink), but returns array with url => "t3://page?uid=19"

Comment: nevermind, had something in the page getter that manipulated the string... Thanks!

Comment: Doesn´t solved my noobish mistake, but could help others if they search for the keywords ;)